# How to get class of a div with specific ID on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get class of each div with a specific id when clicked.

Here is what I tried.

```
$("#chng").click(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   alert(myClass);
});
```

This works only on first div and not others.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="chng" class="a"></div>
<br/>
<div id="chng" class="b"></div>
<br/>
<div id="chng" class="c"></div>
<br/>
<div id="chng" class="d"></div>
```

I have a hint that each() function can be used here but I don't know how to use it. Please provide with a solution for this. Also is it possible to get url of background image I assign to these div on click?

```
background: url(bg1.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: IDs are required to be unique.

Comment: As already stated, IDs __must__ be unique, If they are __not__, then the DOM would return __only__ the first match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch it around.

Make the id's your classes and your classes your ids.
IDs **must be unique** and your classes do not have to be.

HTML:

```
<div class="chng" id="a"></div>
<br/>
<div class="chng" id="b"></div>
<br/>
<div class="chng" id="c"></div>
<br/>
<div class="chng" id="d"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(".chng").click(function() {
   var myID = this.id;
   alert(myID);
});
```

Comment: Or just add chng as a class and keep the current a, b, c, d, classes the same

Comment: @justnS baaah. Too confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should detect click on elements by `class` attribute, and get the `id`'s of the divs clicked.

Comment: The issue here is that he is using multiple identical `id`s.

Comment: He knows that...  He's pointing out that the OP is doing it backwards.

Comment: For that, the `class` must be unique and the `id` is different foreach element.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Re-reading it, I think I see what he means now, but this answer could be taken in such a way that identical `id`s would be kept in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

IDs are supposed to be unique, so you should swap your class names and IDs to make it look like this:

```
<div id="a" class="chng"></div>
<br/>
<div id="b" class="chng"></div>
<br/>
<div id="c" class="chng"></div>
<br/>
<div id="d" class="chng"></div>
```

then what I would do in JQuery is:

```
$(".chng").click(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("id");
   alert(myClass);
});
```

Here's a simple fiddle with my modified version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/cVYVf/4/

Comment: Use `this.id` :-P no need to check `attr`

Answer (score 0):

Because `id` should be unique and you can't use same id for multiple elements. That's why it's working only on first div and not others.

To get background image you can use `$(this).css('background-image')`

Example:

HTML

```
<div class="chng" id="a"></div>
<br/>
<div class="chng" id="b"></div>
<br/>
<div class="chng" id="c"></div>
<br/>
<div class="chng" id="d"></div>
```

JS

```
$('.chng').click(function() {
    alert($(this).css('background-image').replace('url("', '').replace('")', ''));
});
```

CSS

```
.chng {height: 100px;}
#a {background: #ccc url(bg1.jpg) no-repeat;}
#b {background: red url(bg2.jpg) no-repeat;}
#c {background: blue url(bg3.jpg) no-repeat;}
#d {background: green url(bg4.jpg) no-repeat;}
```

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/NvuAk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The ID must be unique in a document.

Answer (score 0):

To select something by the ID and class, you need to use the selector statement.

```
$("#id.classname").click(foo);
```

or in this case

```
$("#chng.a(or any other class)").click(foo);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fzrTN/ - jsfiddle with something to the effect

EDIT 2:

But as has already been stated, it'd just be easier to make unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Id can't be twice in a same page, so you can use alternate option, such as name or rel

```
$("div[rel=chng]").click(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   alert(myClass);
});
```

change id into rel in html code

```
<div rel="chng" class="a"></div>
<br/>
<div rel="chng" class="b"></div>
<br/>
<div rel="chng" class="c"></div>
<br/>
<div rel="chng" class="d"></div>
```

Hope it should work

Comment: rel? Why not just use `class`?!

Comment: some lightbox reminescence in background maybe :)